# How to remove or disable address bar in ipad safari?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ipad, safari

I have a web application. When I am running my web app on the iPad ... I need to hide or disable the address bar in safari browser with iPad.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a feature that the Safari web browser on iOS provides websites with. When you see this done in iOS, it's because the application is creating a UIWebView on it's own ViewController. You might be able to scroll the page down on page load, however. This would cause the navigation bar to be "hidden" until the user interacted with it or scrolled up.